# Applying list of strings on like operator

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

**problem statement:** I need to pass a list of string and apply like operator using filter function in spark java.

**Reason:**  like operator considers a single string entity, so there is lot of performance issue in the code as we need to apply on larger dataset, to overcome this problem
 I need to pass the list of string and apply like operator using filter function.

So kindly let me know how to apply list using like. as I need to find similar patterns of ID's

```
 JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
  SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
  SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaTokenizerExample").getOrCreate();

  List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
      RowFactory.create("J40504", "CRC Industries"),
      RowFactory.create("K630-0746777","Dixon value"),
      RowFactory.create("K444-4444","3M INdustries"),
      RowFactory.create("4333444","3M INdustries"),
      RowFactory.create("566-655","3M INdustries"),
      RowFactory.create("4444888","3M INdustries"),
      RowFactory.create("P477-7444","3M INdustries"),
      RowFactory.create("566655","Dixon coupling valve"));
   // In real time we have large dataset

  StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {new StructField("label1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("sentence1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()) });

  Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

  List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
  listStrings.add("40504");
  listStrings.add("630-0746");
  listStrings.add("477-7444");
  listStrings.add("444-4444");
// In real time we have large list of string to be compared with
  sentenceDataFrame.show();
  System.out.println("Array list :"+listStrings);
  for(int i=0;i<listStrings.size();i++){
 sentenceDataFrame=sentenceDataFrame.filter(col("label1").like("%"+listStrings.get(i)+"%"));
  }
  sentenceDataFrame.show();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First Solution**

Instead of iterate over the dataset N (where N is the size of **listStrings**) number of times you can build the expression and filter the dataset one time only:

```
    StringBuilder expressionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String separator = "";

    for (String s : listStrings) {
        expressionBuilder.append(separator + " label1 LIKE '%" + s + "%'");
        separator = " OR ";
    }

    String expression = expressionBuilder.toString();

    sentenceDataFrame = sentenceDataFrame.filter(expression);
```

**Second Solution**

We can load the listStrings into a Dataset:

```
 StructType schemaList = new StructType(new StructField[]{new StructField("labelToFind", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())});

 List<Row> listStrings = Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create("40504"),
                RowFactory.create("630-0746"),
                RowFactory.create("477-7444"),
                RowFactory.create("444-4444"));

 Dataset<Row>listDataset = sqlContext.createDataFrame(listStrings, schemaList);
```

and then we can Join the two datasets in order to filter the rows:

```
   sentenceDataFrame = sentenceDataFrame.join(listDataset ,sentenceDataFrame.col("label1").contains(listDataset.col("labelToFind"))).select("label1","sentence1");
```

Comment: @BHANUMATHIHM you are welcome, If in the next few days there will be no better answers, can you check the answer as correct? :-)

Comment: @Griffo, In my case I have huge number of records("liststrings" is having more than 500 records) when I tried the above approach for my case it is giving below exceptions

1) "failed to compile: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Code of method "()V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator" grows beyond 64 KB"

2) Code of method "(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Z" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate" grows beyond 64 KB

Any works with respect to this issue.

Comment: @BHANUMATHIHM In your case the Spark SQL's code generator  exceeds the 64KB JVM limit because you have more than 500 records. In your problem statement you didn't declare this constraint.

Comment: @Griffo, while posting I mentioned in the comment
 "// In real time we have large dataset" 

"// In real time we have large list of string to be compared with"
 can u help me to get out of this problem, How can I approach further to handle 500 or more records?

Comment: @BHANUMATHIHM I have an idea to obtain the same outcome using join, give me a change to try and then I let you know.

Comment: @BHANUMATHIHM I've added a second solution, let me know if It works.